# To show that for every continuous function there exists some other continuous function satisfying this conditions

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Suppose that we start with some continuous function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$. Since it is continuous it is integrable so the number $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ exists.

> How to show (in an as elementary as possible way) that there exist continuous function $g$ such that we have $f \neq g$ and $\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)-g(x))dx=0$?

This is geometrically obvious but how to prove it?

Comment: This is to hold for all $a,b$ or just one particular choice?

Comment: @lulu One choice.

Answer (score 2):

We know that there's a $c\in [a,b] $ such that $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx =f(c)(b-a)$.  Just let $g(x):=f(c)$.

Edit: In case $f$ is constant of value $c$, choose the straight line connecting $(a,c-1)$ and $(b,c+1)$.

Comment: What if $f$ is constant? Then you won't satisfy the condition $f \neq g$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Integral a satisfy the equation $$\int f(x)+\int g(x)=\int(f(x)+g(x))dx$$ so if you pick any continuous function $g$ such that $\int fdx=\int gdx$ it will work.

For an explicit example, you can "reverse" $f$ on $[a,b]$ by finding a function such that $g(a)=f(b),g(b)=f(a)$, and the points between are likewise reflected across $\frac{b-a}{2}$